# Se puede interactuar con una web desde app android y retornar los valores resultados?

Tags: android, firebase

Puedo enviar valores de un edittex de android a un campo de texto de una pagina web, (sería esta: http://consulta.tse.gob.sv/), aceptar el captcha, precionar el botón respectivo y retornar a mi app android la respuesta de la pagina? existen 2 respuestas posibles, que el documento único no existe y los datos completos que identifican a la persona dueña de ese documento.
Mi idea es verificar la identidad de los usuarios de mi app de esta forma.

Comment: si la web no tiene definida una API o forma de interactuar, no podras

Comment: Si que se puede interactuar porque al final no deja de ser una llamada get/post que tienes que replicar... pero el captcha te lo va a dificultar bastante a mi parecer. Lo que yo haría sería usar un webview que accediese a esa página y una vez se loguee correctamente seguir a una nueva actividad. También podrías obtener los html a pelo y parsear la información a componentes nativos de android.

Comment: Entonces es posible acceder a la Url con un webview, realizar el proceso necesario en la página (escribir número de identidad, aceptar el captcha, precionar el botón) y luego poder capturar el resultado obtenido? Cuando el resultado es el esperado la página muestra el nombre completo de la persona, ciudad y dirección de residencia, entre otros. Es posible pasar esa información a el hilo principal en la actividad?

Comment: Cuando llenas el webview, ya tienes el contenido, asi que sí bien podes pasarlo a otro objeto. Asi es como funcionan las app de saldo TUC. Se conectaban al sitio, engañaban en "captcha" que era demasiado debil, y recuperaban el saldo TUC. Ahora ya pusieron un captcha mas profesional, y dejaron de funcionanr las apps menos la de ellos..